# SQL Server: if I don't specify a RECOVERY mode for a RESTORE DATABASE, what is the default?

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187495.aspx

Example:

--Restore the regular log backup (from backup set 2).

```
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2008R2
FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2008R2FullRM.bak'
WITH FILE=2, 
NORECOVERY;
```

My question: If I don't specify `NORECOVERY`, will it be the default? I have a bunch of databases that were migrated in this fashion and I'm not sure how to tell which recovery model was used.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RECOVERY is the default. See the documentation for the [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) command, which states:

> Comparison of RECOVERY and NORECOVERY
>
> Roll back is controlled by the RESTORE statement through the [
>   RECOVERY | NORECOVERY ] options:
>
> NORECOVERY specifies that roll back not occur. This allows roll
>   forward to continue with the next statement in the sequence.
>
> In this case, the restore sequence can restore other backups and roll
>   them forward.
>
> RECOVERY (the default) indicates that roll back should be performed
>   after roll forward is completed for the current backup.
>
> Recovering the database requires that the entire set of data being
>   restored (the roll forward set) is consistent with the database. If
>   the roll forward set has not been rolled forward far enough to be
>   consistent with the database and RECOVERY is specified, the Database
>   Engine issues an error.